# Microsoft graph Notifications stopped working

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I've created some Subscriptions for certain inboxes many months ago, and system successfully received notifications about received emails, also subscriptions are regularly updated to increase expiration dates.
Here's the list of my subscriptions:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions/

{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#subscriptions",
"value": [
{
"id": "ef4d00ca-cf0c-4da6-bded-1ab47295e3f5",
"resource": "users/622eee14-9413-49e3-ac53-10148eba09be/messages",
"applicationId": "281e7aa8-7ef8-4a02-9195-83ffb149d95c",
"changeType": "created",
"clientState": null,
"notificationUrl": "https://...",
"expirationDateTime": "2019-12-03T23:00:03.0238504Z",
"creatorId": "2ca67f35-32ba-4ef5-99ab-6686a93e0007"
},
{
"id": "6f056383-df34-47b5-aaf2-dce3fca1c511",
"resource": "users/3ccbd0c8-f11e-4bac-99df-27b78be74aaa/messages",
"applicationId": "281e7aa8-7ef8-4a02-9195-83ffb149d95c",
"changeType": "created",
"clientState": null,
"notificationUrl": "https://...",
"expirationDateTime": "2019-12-03T23:00:01.4332477Z",
"creatorId": "2ca67f35-32ba-4ef5-99ab-6686a93e0007"
}
]
}
```

But starting today (2019-12-02) system stopped receiving notifications.
Then I've created subscription with my test account
subscription was created successfully,
calling https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions/, I've received response

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#subscriptions",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "dfefbb04-887f-439f-bb09-a6075eeca8cd",
            "resource": "users/ebaeb8ab-44c1-40e1-8725-635759c035db/messages",
            "applicationId": "57afcb67-6089-4abc-bba8-2470ce9c22ec",
            "changeType": "created",
            "clientState": null,
            "notificationUrl": "https://63efa1ea.ngrok.io/api/Core/MailNotification/Listen",
            "expirationDateTime": "2019-12-04T13:10:14.2380272Z",
            "creatorId": "6a046ec1-ec01-43de-83b8-0e0696e89ecf"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've tried sending email to mailbox, mentioned above, but still I receive no notifications.
Does something changed to Ms Graph? Is there a way to troubleshoot this problem, can I see some logs in azure portal or somewhere else, did MS Graph tried to send me a notification? Or it just suddenly stopped working?

Answer (score 1):

It seems there was a degradation of service that affected Microsoft Graph Exchange services from 30th November '19. This seems to have been resolved as indicated from this [comment](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/6462#issuecomment-562224301).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related to a current problem with Graph Subscriptions that I have as well. There is a [Github Issue](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/6462) of this, with several reports of this problem.

Comment: Re-opened issue [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/6476) since author closed it and still not resolved

Comment: The Issues have been closed and I did not have any problems for months now.